# Can a graphql query or mutation return a scalar value

Tags: graphql

Syntactically you can define a query or a mutation in the schema such that it returns a type.
However, an operation definition (i.e a query or mutation invoked by a client) has to have a SelectionSet, so I have to do:

```
mutation X { field }
```

So the result of my mutation or query has to be an object with fields, it can't be a scalar. 
Is this right? It feels like I ought to be able to just return a scalar. The result is always wrapped in an envelope when sending across HTTP, so the result would be valid JSON either way (a simple scalar isn't strictly valid JSON).

Is my reading correct?

Answer (score 47):

You can actually return a scalar, like `Boolean` or `String`

```
type Mutation {
  hello(who: String!): String
}
```

The issuing this query

```
mutation foo {
  hello("peter")
}
```

result would look like this

```
data.hello // string
```

Tested this with graphql-yoga + graphql-playground:

[image: schema from playground]
[image: result from playground]

Comment: Using what? When I tried, GraphiQL doesn't like the syntax, and the spec apparently doesn't allow it. I suspect that server implementation DO allow that, but  in the spec the definition of an operation is that it is followed by SelectionSet and *not* SelectionSet(opt)

Comment: I am playing with graphql-yoga and "graphql playground" and the examples works ...

Comment: Yes, GraphiQL also seems to like it, but the *spec* would appear to indicate it's invalid. Since I want to return scalars, I'll take reality over the spec!

Comment: @TomQuarendon the example above is valid according to the spec.  The mutation name is followed by a selection set that contains the hello field.

Comment: I did't find a statement about scalar types in request results in the GraphQL Schema, but this example: https://spec.graphql.org/June2018/#example-50137 Seems like it's considered to return a String from a query.